# Could Godzilla's atomic breath feed the MUTOs with radiation?

Tags: godzilla, godzilla-2014, monsterverse

Coming from this question [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/60739/are-the-mutos-radioactive-or-not), would Godzilla's nuclear/atomic breath not feed the MUTOs with radiation, seeing that his breath is, as the name suggests, nuclear based? Seeing that the MUTOs do infact eat nuclear ordnance as a source of food and "fuel", it would make sense that any form of radiation (maybe even the Sun?) would suffice as a food source, right?

The scene in question is in 2014's Godzilla, when Godzilla resorts to using his atomic breath against the MUTOs during the final fight in San Francisco.

Comment: My assumption was that the "atomic breath" was **plasma**. Yes, it might be radioactive but the sheer *power* killed the MUTO. It's like, ""We need water to live right? Sure, now drink this fire hose on full stream"....it'll kill you.

Comment: https://nerdist.com/godzillas-atomic-breath-is-much-more-destructive-than-it-looks/

Comment: @Paulie_D I completely forgot about the destructive aspect of Godzilla's atomic breath. Oh gosh, now I feel stupid. An absolute rookie mistake.